# Random num Generator/ odd and even

Tags: javascript, html

I need to figure out how to make a random number generator from 1-100 using HTML javascript. After finding the number from 1-100 I need to tell whether the number is odd or even. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>By clicking this button you will genarte a number from 1 to 100 </p> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("demo")
x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

if (a%==0)
    system.out.println("Even Number");
else
    system.out.println("Odd Number");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think I have the random number generator right, but not the odd or even.
Please help.

Comment: read what `%` operator is, and how to use it, then change `a%==0` change to `a%2==0` - also, `Int` ? this is not JAVA, this is javascript (you also tagged the question java!?) hint: browsers have a **developer** tools console - you'll see errors in it with the code you've written

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: This is half java half javascript.  It's not gonna work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing java / javascript, to show you the code first:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>By clicking this button you will genarte a number from 1 to 100 </p> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("demo");
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  ele.innerHTML = number

  if (number%2==0) {
    alert("Even Number");
  }
  else {
    alert("Odd Number");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is no `system.out.println` in Javascript, you needed some more brackets and lastly to check for even check you missed a `%2`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have mixed up Java and JavaScript a little bit.  JavaScript is what runs in browser, Java is a VM you download (and can sometimes run in browser, if you have the extension enabled/installed).  `system.out.println` is Java.  I went ahead and changed stuff out to make it entirely JavaScript.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo"),
      randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  x.innerHTML = randomNum
  if (randomNum % 2 == 0) {
      console.log("Even Number");
  } else {
      console.log("Odd Number");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>By clicking this button you will genarte a number from 1 to 100 </p> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```